# How to generate sql select with dynamic order by

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to compare contents of different databases with the same tables. Some of them have a very low rowcount, so I though I'd compare them visually for starters.

So I'm trying to generate a sql-command in the form of:

```
select * from [tablename] order by 1,2,etc
```

So far, I've got:

```
select 'select * from ' || ut.table_name || ' order by ' ||
       (select listagg(num,', ') within group(order by num) csv
          from (        select rownum num
                          from dual
              connect by level <= (select count(*) c
                                     from user_tab_columns
                                    where table_name = 'TABLE99')
                       ))
  from user_tables ut
 where ut.table_name = 'TABLE99';
```

which generates:

```
select * from TABLE99 order by 1, 2, 3, 4
```

I want to join the user_tables and user_tab_columns on table_name so I can generate it for all of the tables in the schema. Unfortunately simply doing table_name = ut.table_name doesn't work.

How can I join user_tables and user_tab_columns?

Comment: Why does it not work? It should imo.

Comment: @kutschkem: Oracle returns the error   ORA-00904: "UT"."TABLE_NAME": invalid ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query instead. I will count the number of columns per table using row_number().  Hope this helps. Thanks.

```
select 'select * from ' || ut.table_name || ' order by ' ||
      listagg(num,', ') within group(order by num) query
from (
  select table_name,
         row_number() over (partition by table_name order by col_name) as num
  from user_tab_columns) t, user_tables ut
where ut.table_name=t.table_name  
group by ut.table_name  
order by ut.table_name 

Result:
query
select * from TABLE99 order by 1, 2, 3, 4
select * from TABLE98 order by 1, 2
```

Comment: thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I only had to replace 'order by col_name' with 'order by column_name', perhaps a Oracle version difference?

Comment: Nope. it is not due to oracle version but typo error on my part. I created the column name in my testing table as col_name instead of   column_name. Thanks.